# Como recorro el data para solo coja el nombre del personaje en Java?

Tags: java, json, api

Como recorro el data para solo coja el nombre del personaje en Java??
Tengo este json y lo unico que quiero sacar es el nombre en este caso Aatrox, Ahri,...
La url del json es esta http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/12.7.1/data/es_ES/champion.json

```
 "type": "champion",
    "format": "standAloneComplex",
    "version": "12.7.1",
    "data": {
        "Aatrox": {
            "version": "12.7.1",
            "id": "Aatrox",
            "key": "266",
            "name": "Aatrox",
            "title": "la Espada de los Oscuros",
            "blurb": "Aatrox y sus hermanos, otrora respetados defensores de Shurima contra el Vacío...",
           
        "Ahri": {
            "version": "12.7.1",
            "id": "Ahri",
            "key": "103",
            "name": "Ahri",
            "title": "La Mujer Zorro de nueve Colas",
            "blurb": "Ahri es una vastaya conectada de forma innata al poder latente de Runaterra, y es capaz de convertir la magia en orbes de energía pura.",
          
        }
    }
```

Tengo esto pero me lo saca entero lo de dentro del data

```
JSONObject json = readJsonFromUrl("http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/12.7.1/data/es_ES/champion.json"); 
System.out.println(json.get("data"));
```

Ayuda porfavor he intentado muchas cosas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero, obtienes el objeto `data` con `.getJSONObject`. Luego, dado que los nombres que necesitas son las claves de ese objeto, pues los obtienes tienes simplemente con el método `.keySet()`. Quedaría:

```
JSONObject json = readJsonFromUrl("http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/12.7.1/data/es_ES/champion.json"); 
Set<String> nombres = json.getJSONObject("data").keySet();
System.out.println(nombres);
```

Dando como salida en la consola:

```
[Jax, Sona, Tristana, Yuumi, Seraphine, Varus, Kaisa, Fiora, Singed, Samira, TahmKench, Leblanc, Thresh, Karma, Lillia, Jhin, Rumble, Udyr, LeeSin, Yorick, Ornn, Kayn, Neeko, Kassadin, Sivir, MissFortune, Senna, Draven, Yasuo, Kayle, Rell, Shaco, Renekton, Hecarim, Fizz, KogMaw, Yone, Maokai, Lissandra, Jinx, Urgot, Fiddlesticks, Galio, Pantheon, Talon, Gangplank, Sett, Ezreal, Gnar, Teemo, Annie, Mordekaiser, Azir, Kennen, Riven, Chogath, Aatrox, Poppy, Taliyah, Illaoi, Pyke, Heimerdinger, Alistar, XinZhao, Lucian, Volibear, Sejuani, Nidalee, Garen, Leona, Zed, Blitzcrank, Rammus, Velkoz, Caitlyn, Trundle, Kindred, Renata, Akshan, Vex, Quinn, Ekko, Nami, Swain, Aphelios, Sylas, Taric, Syndra, Rakan, Skarner, Gwen, Braum, Veigar, Xerath, Corki, Nautilus, Ahri, Jayce, Darius, Tryndamere, Janna, Elise, Vayne, Brand, Zoe, Graves, Soraka, Xayah, Viego, Karthus, Vladimir, Zilean, Katarina, Shyvana, Warwick, Ziggs, Kled, Khazix, Olaf, TwistedFate, Nunu, Qiyana, Rengar, Bard, Irelia, Ivern, MonkeyKing, Ashe, Kalista, Akali, Vi, Amumu, Lulu, Morgana, Nocturne, Diana, AurelionSol, Zyra, Viktor, Cassiopeia, Nasus, Twitch, DrMundo, Zeri, Orianna, Evelynn, RekSai, Lux, Sion, Camille, MasterYi, Ryze, Malphite, Anivia, Shen, JarvanIV, Malzahar, Zac, Gragas]
```

Si necesitas iterarlo uno por uno:

```
for (String  nombre: nombres) {
     System.out.println(nombre);
}
```

Comment: vale, y como lo deberia hacer para sacarlo de 1 en 1, tipo [Jax] [Sona]

Comment: No entendí tu pregunta. Es un set, puedes hacer de todo con él. Usar streams, convertirlo a lista, iterarlo...

Comment: sois todos muy grandes, muchísimas gracias, llevaba días atascado

Answer (score 0):

Sería algo así:

```
    JSONObject json = readJsonFromUrl("http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/12.7.1/data/es_ES/champion.json");        
    //convertir json "data" en arreglo
    JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONObject("data").names();
    //Iterar sobre el arreglo
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        System.out.println(jsonArray.get(i));
    }
```